# Knockout Validation is not working

Tags: knockout-validation

It may be the easiest question but I am not able to resolve this. The validation on my page is not working. Everytime I am submitting the page leaving all the input fields blank, an alert is generated saying 'Failed'. And if I enter all the fields with some value data is successfully submitted.

Here is my HTML :

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Exercise10";
}
<html>
<head>

<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.6.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/knockout-2.2.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/knockout.mapping-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/json2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="../../Content/ExerciseStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="../../Scripts/Popup.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/themes/base/jquery-    ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/DatePicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/knockout.validation.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/knockout-validator.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/knockout-validator-extensions.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="../../Scripts/extensions.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="post">
<div id="MainArea">
    <table id="tbllist" align="center" style="margin-left: 15px; width: 96%; margin-      right: 15px;">
        <tr>
            <th colspan="3" align="left">
                <div id="title_p">
                    Enter Following Entries</div>
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right" style="width: 40%;">
                <b>Name :</b>
            </td>
            <td align="left" style="width: 17%;">
                <input data-bind="value: EmployeeName" placeholder="Employee Name" class="txt"
                    type="text" />
            </td>
            <td align="left">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">
                <b>Emp# :</b>
            </td>
            <td align="left">
                <input data-bind="value: EmployeeCode" placeholder="Employee Code" style="width: 200px;"
                    type="text" />
            </td>
            <td align="left">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">
                <b>Date of Birth :</b>
            </td>
            <td align="left">
                <input data-bind="value: Dob" id="datepicker" placeholder="Date of Birth" style="width: 200px;"
                    type="text" /><span>(dd/mm/yyyy)</span>
            </td>
            <td align="left">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">
                <b>Age (18-60):</b>
            </td>
            <td align="left">
                <input data-bind="value: Age" style="width: 200px;" placeholder="Age Range (18-60)"
                    type="number" min="18" max="60" />
            </td>
            <td align="left">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">
                <b>Contact Number :</b>
            </td>
            <td align="left">
                <input data-bind="value: ContactNumber" placeholder="Contact Number" style="width: 200px;"
                    type="text" />
            </td>
            <td align="left">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">
                <b>Email :</b>
            </td>
            <td align="left">
                <input data-bind="value: EmailID" placeholder="Email ID" style="width: 200px;"
                    type="email" />
            </td>
            <td align="left">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">
                <b>Address :</b>
            </td>
            <td align="left">
                <input data-bind="value: Address" placeholder="Address" style="width: 200px;"
                    type="text" />
            </td>
            <td align="left">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">
                <b>City :</b>
            </td>
            <td align="left">
                <select data-bind="value: City" style="width: 200px;">
                    <option value="Noida">New Delhi</option>
                    <option value="Noida">Noida</option>
                    <option value="Noida">Mumbai</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td align="left">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">
                <b>Marital Status :</b>
            </td>
            <td align="left">
                <input data-bind="checked: MaritalStatus" checked="checked" name="rdb" type="radio" /><span>UnMarried</span>
                <input data-bind="checked: MaritalStatus" checked="checked" name="rdb" type="radio" checked="checked" /><span>Married</span>

            </td>
            <td align="left">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">
                <b>Any Employee Reference :</b>
            </td>
            <td align="left">
                <input data-bind="checked: Is_Reference" type="checkbox" />yes
            </td>
            <td align="left">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table style="width: 99%; margin-right: 20px; padding: 5px;">
            <tr align="right">
                <td>
                    <button data-bind="click :$root.save" class="button">Save</button>
                    <input type="button" id="btnCancel" class="button" value="Cancel" onclick="JavaScript:closePopup();" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
</div>
</form>
```

And My View Model (continued from the above):

```
<script type="text/javascript">



//....................................................//
    var EmpViewModel = function () {


        //Make the self as 'this' reference
        var self = this;
        //Declare observable which will be bind with UI 
        self.EmployeeCode = ko.observable("").extend({ required: true });
        self.EmployeeName = ko.observable("").extend({ required: { message: 'Please supply your Name.'} });
        self.Dob = ko.observable("");
        self.Age = ko.observable("").extend({number :true});
        self.ContactNumber = ko.observable("");
        self.EmailID = ko.observable("");
        self.Address = ko.observable("");
        self.MaritalStatus = ko.observable("");
        self.City = ko.observable("");
        self.Is_Reference = ko.observable("");

        //The Object which stored data entered in the observables
        var EmpData = {
            EmpCode: self.EmployeeCode,
            EmpName: self.EmployeeName,
            Dob: self.Dob,
            Age: self.Age,
            ContactNumber: self.ContactNumber,
            MaritalStatus: self.MaritalStatus,
            EmailID: self.EmailID,
            Address: self.Address,
            City: self.City,
            Is_Reference: self.Is_Reference
        };

        //Declare an ObservableArray for Storing the JSON Response
        self.Employees = ko.observableArray([]);

        //Function to perform POST (insert Employee) operation
        self.save = function () {
            //Ajax call to Insert the Employee
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Exercise/Save/",
                data: ko.toJSON(this), //Convert the Observable Data into JSON
                contentType: "application/json",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("Failed");
                }
            });
            //Ends Here
        };
    }

    ko.applyBindings(new EmpViewModel());
</script>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Knockout-validation shows validation messages only if the fields are modified. Therefore you should check on submit if all fields are valid and show all errors if not.

```
 self.errors = ko.validation.group(this, { deep: true, observable: false });

  //Function to perform POST (insert Employee) operation
        self.save = function () {
            // check if valid
            if(self.errors().length > 0) {
                self.errors.showAllMessages();
                return;
            }
            //Ajax call to Insert the Employee
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Exercise/Save/",
                data: ko.toJSON(this), //Convert the Observable Data into JSON
                contentType: "application/json",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("Failed");
                }
            });
            //Ends Here
 };
```

I have created a fiddle to show that: http://jsfiddle.net/delixfe/tSzYf/2/

Comment: Thanks a lot....awesome its working..Thanks for giving your precious time..ahaha..

Comment: The 'observable: false' is a nice tibit that was difficult to find in documentation

Comment: I am not sure what ko validation does, but it seems like in the fiddle above there is no validation beyond the red outline but that doesn't seem to come from KO. Can someone confirm it's still working?